# Creating DbContext at runtime using DryIoc with Asp.Net Web Api app

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac, dryioc

I want to do something like this `Autofac` line below with `DryIoC`

```
builder.RegisterType<TenantDBContext>
().InstancePerLifetimeScope().WithParameter(new 
NamedParameter("connectionString", ""));
```

I have a `CoreDBContext` that has the connection string of `TenantDBContext`. Is it valid to pass the connection string at the point of registering my context in `DryIoc`?

Answer (score 2):

```
container.Register<DbContext>(
    Reuse.InCurrentScope,
    made: Parameters.Of.Name("connectionString", _ => ""));
```

#### Update:

Asuming that you want to automatically select from multiple constructors:

Here is [live snippet](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6fMDlg)

```
container.Register<DbContext>(
    Reuse.InCurrentScope,
    made: Made.Of(FactoryMethod.ConstructorWithResolvableArguments,
        Parameters.Of.Name("connectionString", _ => "")));
```

Note, that version above is brittle to parameter name change, so you may consider strongly-typed constructor expression:

```
container.Register<DbContext>(
    Made.Of(() => new DbContext("")),
    reuse: Reuse.InCurrentScope);
```

Comment: Thank you @dadhi.I replaced with your code in my IocDependencyResolver class but i got this error "Unspecified how to select single constructor from type DryIocSample.Data.TenantDBContext with multiple public constructors:
Void .ctor();
Void .ctor(System.String)" . 

Could it be because i didn't resolve the parameter name in my repository like i did with Autofac with code below

get { return _container.Resolve<TenantDBContext>(new NamedParameter("connectionString", _tenantConfig.Configuration.Connectionstring)); }

Thanks for your help.

Comment: arrrgggggggggg!!! still not working. Looks like i'm missing something, shouldn't i resolve this in my repository too ?

Comment: Hi, I fixed a typo and provided the link to full sample.